# getElementById breaks script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a little project, but I'm stuck and don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I use Ajax to call a php-script that updates a MYSQL-row.

The javascript:

```
function savecust()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("custdetails").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","./ajax/savecust.php?id=" + document.getElementById('id').value,true); //More arguments should still be passed.
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If I remove the `document.getElementById('id').value` the script works and does what is is supposed to do. (I get the response from the PHP, obviously

I load the script in the head of the page along with some other scripts:

```
<script src="js/custedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is how I call the script:

```
<input type='button' onclick='savecust()' value='Save' />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;-).

Thanks!

### EDIT

- The div where the content should go, exists.
- The PHP-scripts returns an error for now (because it doesn't get all the required parameters)
- The content (and textfield with id: 'id') is loaded by another script. Is this a problem? If you look at the source in a browser the textfields are not there. They are however visible in the browser.

### EDIT 2

So, I ran this test on top of my script:

```
var thisid = 'id';//should get info from <input type='text' name='id' />
var T = document.getElementById(thisid);
if (T) {
     alert("element exists" + T.value);
} else {
alert("nothing to be found");
}
```

It is indeed unable to find the element. This pointed me in the right direction.
`<input type='text' name='id' />`is inserted by another Ajax-script. So I think the second script is unable to find it.

How do I solve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Have you tried to alert `document.getElementById('id').value`?

Comment: What's it doing when it fails? Do you get an error message? Is the Javascript failing or the PHP? Why not use jQuery (or similar) which would make this much easier?

Comment: You probably are missing an element with id = "id".
document.getElementById('id') will return null if it does not find an element.

document.getElementById('id').value ​​will give you this error if no element was found:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access an element property if it does not exist.

Perhaps a test:

```
var thisid = 'id';//whatever it REALLY is...
    var T = document.getElementById(thisid);
    if (T) {
         alert("element exists" + T.value);
    }
```

Comment: The element can't be found by the script. See edit on top. How do I get around this?

Comment: I think what you are going to have to do is have the second (inserter) script call the function in the first script to do the stuff you need.

Comment: NOTE: you are making the ASSUMPTION here (from evidence of notes etc) that name="id" is the same as id="id" - test with ACTUAL id="id" if possible.  I think (no citation) that the name==id assumption is deprecated functionality.

Comment: One other note: The reason for that is that in IE, getElementById finds and returns the meta element whose name attribute has the value description before it gets to the input element - try changing the "id" to "idme" or something unique and NOT the same as the attribute. (and try adding an actual id='idme') if that fails.

Comment: One final thought: name= is valid for FORM element contents, but if you are injecting the element, I am NOT sure how the name= and id= translation will be handled, if at all and hence why the id= would be a good test/fix perhaps? in this example instance.  AND if it is NOT in a FORM, likely it is not doing that at all.

Comment: OMG I'm ready to shoot myself true the head! 'name' is clearly not the same as 'id'. Thanks guys +1 for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason is that there is no field whose id is `id` or the HTML has not been fully loaded when the script runs.

You should check your browser's script errors (use Firebug with Firefox or press F12 on Internet Explorer)